# Broken UL Based JQuery Menu on IE and Firefox WIndows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists

I have a menu with jquery and css at the following link.  Works great on mac browsers, but is totally broken on windows, I have been working on this for hours and was curious if some kind hearted programmer could have a peek at it and see what I am doing wrong.  It is supposed to start with the menu revealing the current page, which works, but the hovering action does not work at all in my tests on windows. (Firefox and IE).

http://www.chipmandesignarch.com/sustainable-design-leed-accredited-architects.php

Comment: It works for me (Google Chrome on Linux and Windows), either way it might be related to browser support -- do you mind giving us more details about the browsers you're trying with?

Comment: Thanks for checking!
I am seeing problems with Firefox 3.6.18 and IE 8 on windows xp.
The menu should respond to rollover to show up to 3 tiers depending on the selection. For example Who We Are->Leadership->Daniel...

Comment: OK, turns out i should take out the console log lines....these were breaking it..thanks for checking it guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to the javascript choking on the Console.log lines that I had in there for debugging.